# What languages does Pluma / Gedit text editor cover for syntax highlighting?

Tags: gedit

I've tried a Google search and even tried Wikipedia.

https://projects.gnome.org/gedit/ says:

Features:
...
*Configurable syntax highlighting for various languages (C, C++, Java, HTML, XML, Python, Perl and many others)*

This is the closest thing I could find.

Is there a complete list of languages including those others? (C# must also be included as well right?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know what "pluma" is but gedit 3.6 supports the following languages:

```
[04:56 PM] /usr/share/gtksourceview-3.0/language-specs $ ls
actionscript.lang  dpatch.lang            language.dtd    po.lang
ada.lang           dtd.lang               language.rng    prolog.lang
asp.lang           eiffel.lang            latex.lang      protobuf.lang
automake.lang      erlang.lang            libtool.lang    puppet.lang
awk.lang           fcl.lang               lua.lang        python3.lang
bennugd.lang       forth.lang             m4.lang         python.lang
bibtex.lang        fortran.lang           makefile.lang   R.lang
boo.lang           fsharp.lang            mallard.lang    rpmspec.lang
cg.lang            gap.lang               markdown.lang   ruby.lang
changelog.lang     gdb-log.lang           matlab.lang     scheme.lang
chdr.lang          glsl.lang              mxml.lang       scilab.lang
check-language.sh  go.lang                nemerle.lang    sh.lang
c.lang             gtk-doc.lang           netrexx.lang    sml.lang
cmake.lang         gtkrc.lang             nsis.lang       sparql.lang
cobol.lang         haddock.lang           objc.lang       sql.lang
cpp.lang           haskell.lang           objj.lang       systemverilog.lang
csharp.lang        haskell-literate.lang  ocaml.lang      t2t.lang
css.lang           html.lang              ocl.lang        tcl.lang
cuda.lang          idl.lang               octave.lang     texinfo.lang
def.lang           imagej.lang            ooc.lang        vala.lang
desktop.lang       ini.lang               opal.lang       vbnet.lang
diff.lang          java.lang              opencl.lang     verilog.lang
d.lang             javascript.lang        pascal.lang     vhdl.lang
docbook.lang       j.lang                 perl.lang       xml.lang
dosbatch.lang      json.lang              php.lang        xslt.lang
dot.lang           language2.rng          pkgconfig.lang  yacc.lang
[04:56 PM] /usr/share/gtksourceview-3.0/language-specs $
```

Comment: Pluma is a text editor that was forked from Gedit and comes included with the MATE desktop environment (Common in Mint distros). Thanks for the list. I checked the same directory as yours and my version of Pluma came up with 99 languages. Whereas your version of Gedit had 104. Good to know. Thanks!