# Is there a way to get syntax highlighting for Raku lang in Pluma / Gedit?

Tags: gedit, plugins, programming, text-editor

This question is related to [What languages does Pluma / Gedit text editor cover for syntax highlighting?](https://askubuntu.com/q/322220/1109562). I noticed [Raku](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raku_(programming_language)) programming language is not supported yet by Pluma in Ubuntu Mate 18.04. Following the procedure in that question, I located the following language files:

```
user@machine:/usr/share/gtksourceview-3.0/language-specs$ ls
abnf.lang          c.lang        dosbatch.lang  glsl.lang              jade.lang        logcat.lang     nsis.lang       po.lang        sh.lang             vbnet.lang
actionscript.lang  cmake.lang    dot.lang       go.lang                java.lang        lua.lang        objc.lang       prolog.lang    sml.lang            verilog.lang
ada.lang           cobol.lang    dpatch.lang    groovy.lang            javascript.lang  m4.lang         objj.lang       protobuf.lang  sparql.lang         vhdl.lang
ansforth94.lang    cpphdr.lang   dtd.lang       gtk-doc.lang           j.lang           makefile.lang   ocaml.lang      puppet.lang    sql.lang            xml.lang
asp.lang           cpp.lang      dtl.lang       gtkrc.lang             json.lang        mallard.lang    ocl.lang        python3.lang   sweave.lang         xslt.lang
automake.lang      csharp.lang   eiffel.lang    haddock.lang           julia.lang       markdown.lang   octave.lang     python.lang    swift.lang          yacc.lang
awk.lang           css.lang      erlang.lang    haskell.lang           kotlin.lang      matlab.lang     ooc.lang        R.lang         systemverilog.lang  yaml.lang
bennugd.lang       csv.lang      fcl.lang       haskell-literate.lang  language2.rng    maxima.lang     opal.lang       rpmspec.lang   t2t.lang
bibtex.lang        cuda.lang     forth.lang     haxe.lang              language.dtd     mediawiki.lang  opencl.lang     rst.lang       tcl.lang
bluespec.lang      def.lang      fortran.lang   html.lang              language.rng     meson.lang      pascal.lang     ruby.lang      tera.lang
boo.lang           desktop.lang  fsharp.lang    idl-exelis.lang        latex.lang       modelica.lang   perl.lang       rust.lang      texinfo.lang
cg.lang            diff.lang     gap.lang       idl.lang               lex.lang         mxml.lang       php.lang        scala.lang     thrift.lang
changelog.lang     d.lang        gdb-log.lang   imagej.lang            libtool.lang     nemerle.lang    pig.lang        scheme.lang    toml.lang
chdr.lang          docbook.lang  genie.lang     ini.lang               llvm.lang        netrexx.lang    pkgconfig.lang  scilab.lang    vala.lang
```

I could find plugins providing highlighting for Nano and Atom listed in [their site](https://raku.org/whatever/). Is there any similar plugin for Gedit / Pluma?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Raku language seems to be very modern, so it is not yet supported in gtksourceview. I have filed [bug-report to its developers](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtksourceview/-/issues/149). So it is impossible to add its support to Pluma or Gedit for current releases.

Since 20 May 2020 its support was added to [KDE](https://github.com/KDE/syntax-highlighting/blob/master/data/syntax/raku.xml). So it should work with modern versions of Kate editor.

You can try to install [Kate using FlatPak](https://flathub.org/apps/details/org.kde.kate):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:alexlarsson/flatpak
sudo apt update
sudo apt install flatpak
flatpak remote-add --if-not-exists flathub https://flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo
flatpak install flathub org.kde.kate
```

For first run use `flatpak run org.kde.kate`.
To remove use `flatpak uninstall org.kde.kate`.

Notes:

1. Currently FlatPak provides Kate 20.04.3 without Raku support, so we have to wait.
2. Kate version in Snap [is older](https://snapcraft.io/kate), it is 20.04.1, so it does not have Raku support too.
3. In Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Raku support is [presented](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=focal&arch=amd64&mode=filename&searchon=contents&keywords=raku) in [scite](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/scite) editor. But I will not recommend to upgrade the system to get it installed.