# Difficult to choose a good Pluma syntax highlighting option for simple documentation. Help please?

Tags: document, syntax-highlighting, pluma

I want to write some really simple notes to myself about some code I am writing.

Actually, it would be sufficient just to put e.g. [CODE]...[/CODE] brackets round bits of quoted code so that it appears a different colour.

I found a list at [What languages does Pluma / Gedit text editor cover for syntax highlighting?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/322220/what-languages-does-pluma-gedit-text-editor-cover-for-syntax-highlighting)

But that is rather daunting. I'm not keen to research all the items listed there.

Can anyone recommend a very simple option that would do what I want?

Comment: Simply use Markdown.

Comment: @N0rbert Well, I've installed markdown.lang on my system. I suppose I could also install a special Markdown editor. Pluma highlights it thus, which is not quite what I had in mind: 

>  3a 
Replace
```php
$result = $db->query($sql);
if (DB::isError($result)) {
    etc..
}
```
with
```php
$result = mysqli_query($dsn,$sql);
if (!$result) {
 fp_sql_error_message("my error message");
 exit;
}
```

Comment: Then install ReText and enjoy.